# How to filter products by discount percentage on category page?

Tags: magento2, filter

I want to add a new filter **Discount** on category page. It's values will be something like

```
0-10 %
11-20 %
21-30 %
```

I do not want to import the values of discount attribute with product import which is a manual process. Instead I want to make it dynamic.

Example:
If products base price is 100 and special price is 90, product should be shown in `0-10 %` discount filter.

Can you please share your thoughts about how to achieve it?

Comment: Can it work on Magneto 1.9 too?

Comment: You can utilize the same idea to make it work in 1.9. I have created the module form M2 here https://github.com/amitshree/magento2-discount-percentage-filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope its useful to you, try with this code.

1) create one attribute of type "dropdown" as `discount_percentage`.

2) assign attribute to the product attribute set

3) now for calculation of the product discount you can try using observer  called `catalog_product_save_before` with following code in `observer.php`

```
public function catalog_product_save_before($observer)
{
    $product = $observer->getProduct();
    $product_price = $product->getPrice();
    $product_sp_price = $product->getSpecialPrice();
    $discount_percentage = ($product_sp_price/$product_price)*100;
    $product->setDiscountPercentage($discount_percentage);
    $product->save();
}
```

Note :- before discount is assiging to product the that option should be created previously.for example if the discount is 30% the discount option 30% should be their before or else you have to look how to create this options to dropdown attributes programmatically